# Is there such thing as Custom Data Types?

Tags: mysql, datatypes, type-conversion

Does MySQL have any support for custom data types? For example, zip codes might be stored in a `varchar(10)` field, but they could be compacted in to an `int`, with options for blank, and a flag as to whether it is a 5 digit or 5+4 digit zip code.

Is there a way to install seamless data types for such things? As far as the application is concerned, it would be a string type, there would simply be data truncation (with or without warning), if the application passed invalid data.

Custom functions could be used (for example, there is a built in function `INET_ATON` for IPv4 addresses. But that does not allow for such things as `zip LIKE '12345%'` which should be properly indexed. A well written support for custom data types would allow a data type to be marked as sortable. So the compact `zip int`, when sorted, would sort just as if it was a `zip varchar(10)`.

This would allow for the column to be fixed width, it would allow 6 or 10 byte variable storage to be cut down to 4 byes of fixed width.

There are several applicable uses

- Zip Codes
- IPv6 addresses
- Custom timestamp fields with minute level precision and capacity beyond `2038` with less storage usage than `datetime`, but no need to support dates before the year of implementation (say the min could be 2007 if those are the oldest dates in the system)
- Timestamps that implement DST (which [don't seem to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646171/mysql-datetime-fields-and-daylight-savings-time-how-do-i-reference-the-extra/1650406#1650406))
- Two letter US state can be stored in a single byte
- long `ENUM`s can be separated into a custom data type so that `DESCRIBE`'s output would not be so messy looking with all the wrapping.

I expect the data type handlers would be stored similar to the way functions are stored.

Is there anything remotely like this on any database engine? I mostly use MySQL, but I am curious if this has ever been implemented, short of making the application call a function like the `INET_ATON` function.

[MS SQL does seem to have something of that nature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933121(v=sql.80).aspx), but I would like to know if it is more than just a synonym. (for example `boolean` could be a synonym for `tinyint(1)`, or `postal_code` for one of `char` or `varchar` `(5` or `9` or `10)`) Synonyms are not what I am asking about here.

Comment: simple answer afaik for mysql: no. This would be interesting to see how other RDBMS's handle those things

Comment: @DTest: you have CREATE TYPE in SQL Server: useful for CLR types now. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @George Bailey: your SQL Server link is out of date: it's for SQL Server 2000. And for MySQL see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2451435/27535

Comment: @gbn, (response to first comment) Is type translation included, will it convert for example an `IPv6` into a `binary(16)`, or is it limited to aliasing (which could be used for `state`s becoming `enum`s)

Comment: I don't know, sorry. You can implement this yourself with CLR types. TBH, user defined types (UDTs) aren't often used. I haven't used them since SQL 6.5 back in last millenium. Nowadays I'd use UDFs and/or CHECK CONSTRAINTS with native types.

Comment: @gbn nice link to the so on mysql views. That's creative!

Comment: Please be aware that storing zip-codes as an `int` will _not_ work for an internationalized database - Canada, for example, uses the format of 'A9A A9A'.  Creating a custom data-type for zip-codes is probably a good idea; however, you may wish to re-examine how you are planning on dealing with some of them (storing the state in a single-byte field has potential 'other' issues, for example).  And don't re-implement date/time datatypes, unless the provided ones are un-usuably deficient (size doesn't count) - you'll just confuse people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does MySQL have any support for custom data types?

Simple answer: no

> Is there anything remotely like this on any database engine? I mostly
>   use MySQL, but I am curious if this has ever been implemented, short
>   of making the application call a function like the INET_ATON function.

Oracle has [`CREATE TYPE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_8001.htm#SQLRF01506) which is analogous to some degree to a OO class, including features like member functions and [inheritance](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjint.htm#CHDHECFC)

Postgres has [`CREATE TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtype.html) which is a bit less like OO classes (no member functions or inheritance) but are incredibly flexible and useful, even allowing you to create new base types. There is also [`CREATE DOMAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdomain.html) which allows a form of inheritance or sub-typing and basically extends a base type with some constraints. Postgres also has quite a few interesting base types by default, eg [inet](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-net-types.html) and [geometric](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-geometric.html) types. In Postgres one can write an extension in C for a custom datatype, such as in this example here with [base36 data type](http://big-elephants.com/2015-10/writing-postgres-extensions-part-ii/).

SQL Server has [`CREATE TYPE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007(SQL.90).aspx) which allows you to create a custom data type based on an existing system data type.  For example I could create a type called `SSN` which is basically defined as `VARCHAR(11)` but this way I don't have to remember how big a field it is.

Comment: Please feel free to pile in and edit this answer so we can get a definitive reference. I felt the question lends itself to a CW answer...

Answer (score 1):

[Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org) also has it's solution via [domains](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-custom.html).

> In Firebird, the concept of a “user-defined data type” is implemented
>   in the form of the domain. Creating a domain does not truly create a
>   new data type, of course. A domain provides the means to encapsulate
>   an existing data type with a set of attributes and make this “capsule”
>   available for multiple usage across the whole database. If several
>   tables need columns defined with identical or nearly identical
>   attributes, a domain makes sense.
>
> Domain usage is not limited to column definitions for tables and
>   views. Domains can be used to declare input and output parameters and
>   variables in PSQL code.

Comment: Is Firebird MySQL?

Comment: No, Firebird is Firebird :)
I just mentioned as nother RDMS that has such a feature.